# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: libXrender.so.1

Tags: java, jboss, ubuntu-16.04

When we deploy JBOSS application  getting following exception. server configurations listed bellow

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
..
..
…
  Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

--------------------------------Server Details ------------------------------------

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial


Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                32
```

Comment: Can't remember the details offhand, but this smells like somebody using Swing timers; you need to set the JVM to run in "headless" mode.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- many thanks you are correct when enabled headless issue gone,

Answer (score -1):

set the JVM to run in "headless" mode will solve this problem.

How to do so:

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

Alternatively, you can also use the following command line if you plan to run the same application in both a headless and a traditional environment:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

> Headless mode is a system configuration in which the display device,
> keyboard, or mouse is lacking. Sounds unexpected, but actually you can
> perform different operations in this mode, even with graphic data.
>
> Where it is applicable? Let's say that your application repeatedly
> generates a certain image, for example, a graphical authorization code
> that must be changed every time a user logs in to the system. When
> creating an image, your application needs neither the display nor the
> keyboard. Let's assume now that you have a mainframe or dedicated
> server on your project that has no display device, keyboard, or mouse.
> The ideal decision is to use this environment's substantial computing
> power for the visual as well as the nonvisual features. An image that
> was generated in the headless mode system then can be passed to the
> headful system for further rendering.
> [src](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/headless.html)

Comment: Maybe add a concrete example on how to do that?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to run the command apt install openJDK-8-jre-headless.